# How can I show how many answers are correct and how many are incorrect?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hello I'm new and I want a little help if is possible I want this:
I have 2 check box the first one is "correct" and the second one is "incorrect" but I have 7 screens "I don't use ajax" I want when you finish all the screens when you click "continue button" that it shows the % that is correct and incorrect, also I want to disable continue button but if you click listen button to enable continue button
Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <div id="general"> 
        <div hidden>
            <audio id="audio" src=""></audio>
            <div id="divAudio_Player">
                <audio id="audio_player">
                    <source id="audio_player_ogv" src="" type="audio/ogg" />
                    <source id="audio_player_mp3" src="" type="audio/mpeg" />
                </audio>


</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="plantilla">
            <?php 
            $count = 1;
            while ($count <= 7) {
            ?>          

            <li id="p<?=$count ?>" <?php if ($count==1){echo "class='ver'";} ?> >
                <img src="img/foto<?=$count ?>.jpg" >
                <ul class="sonido" >
                    <li class="record"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> Record (Grabar)</li>
                    <li class="stop"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i> Stop (Detener)</li>
                    <li class="play"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i> Listen 

(Escuchar) </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="pregunta">I want some roast____.</div>
                <input type="button" onclick="checkAnswers()" value="Check answers"  class="boton">

                <div class="respuesta">
                    <input type="button" onclick="play('audio<?=$count ?>')" value="I want some roast beef" class="playsound" >
                    <div  class="opciones">


     <p>Evaluate Yourself</p>
                        <input class="opc1" type="checkbox" value="1" onClick="Califica(1)" />
                        <input class="opc2" type="checkbox" value="2" onClick="Califica(2)" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php
                $count++;
            }
            $count--;
            ?>
            <div class='continuar' ><input type="button" onclick="siguiente()" value="Continuar"  class="button"> </div>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>

<script>
    state = 0 ;
    var pMin  = 1 ;
    var pMax  = <?php echo $count ?> ;
    var respuestas = []


    function play(pfile){
        console.log(pfile);

        var source = '<audio id="audio_player"><source id="audio_player_ogv" src="audios/' + pfile + '.ogg"  type="audio/ogg"  /><source id="audio_player_ogv" src="audios/' + pfile + '.mp3"  type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>';
        $('#divAudio_Player').html(source);
        var aud = $('#audio_player').get(0);
        aud.play();     
    }


function ActivecheckAnswers(e){
        $("#p"+pMin+" .boton").addClass("ver");
    }

    function checkAnswers(e){
        $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta").addClass("ver");

    }


 $(".sonido li").click(function (){
     console.log(this.className);

     });
    function Califica(opc){
        $(".continuar").addClass("ver");
        respuestas[pMin]=opc;
        if (opc==1){
            $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc1").attr('checked', true); 
            $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc2").attr('checked', false);
            $('.opc1').on("click",function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('.button').show();
                                    }
        else{
             $('.button').hide();
            }
                                            });

                   }
        else if (opc==2){
            $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc1").attr('checked', false);
            $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc2").attr('checked', true );  
            $('.opc2').on("click",function(){
             if($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('.button').show();
                                         }
        else{
            $('.button').hide();
            }
                                            });     
                       }
                         };







function siguiente(){
        var aud = $('#audio_player').get(0);
        aud.pause();        

        $(".plantilla .continuar").removeClass("ver");      
        if (pMin<pMax){
            $("#p"+pMin).removeClass("ver") ;
            pMin++;
            $("#p"+pMin).addClass("ver") ;
            state = 0 ;

        }
        alert(respuestas);


    }




</script>
```

Comment: please explain us in other way i did not got you, i just understand you have a form Multi-step form

Comment: Sure, I have 7 screens but only shows one when I continue I put the last one hidden and show the next one but I have 2 check box  one with class opc1 and the other one opc2 but the first one is the correct answer and the second one is incorrect, each time when you click "Continue" it saves if you clicked 1 or 2 (correct or incorrect) but I want to show at final if you click "continue button" How many % is correct(first check box) or incorrect (second one)

Comment: i got you, but what is your problem now :) ?

Comment: Now I only need to have the continue button (disabled) and when I click Listen button to enable the continue button

Comment: man you do not need to waste your time, just google it and find ready (js+css+html) multi-step form then use it easly,, also to count how many "correct" and how mony "incorrect" you should use radio buttons and count the selected buttons at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure I have understand all but you could archive that by doing a count on the clicked1 (correct) and something like this:

```
$finalresult = ($countresult / $totalscreen) * 100;
echo $finalresult;
```

It would show the % result.